# Unity Code for making a sphere roll freezes unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to C# and I need some help with this code. After I added code to make the shift key move the object faster it makes unity freeze. 
This is my code that makes Unity Crash. The only changes are the added variable shift_speed_multiplier and the while statement. https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGnhs.png

Comment: Do not post your code as an image, try writing it

Comment: cant it gave me indenting errors that I couldn't figure out how to fix, monodevelop didn't give me that prob

Comment: Ctrl + K to auto-indent

Comment: Try using an if statement. And use { }.

Comment: hi guys I am closing this. I fixed it with 2 if statements for getkeydown and getkeyup

Answer (score 1):

That `while` statement is being constantly run while the shift key is pressed. Therefore, nothing else (not even other game entities) can be updated. The solution to that is simply to use an `if` instead of a `while`, that will only update the speed once, without running in a loop.